# Altair default color palette colors in HEX

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

How can I find the HEX representation of Altair default color palette? Every plotting tool has its strengths & weaknesses and I typically end up generating visualizations consist of Seaborn + Altair. I would like to match Altair colors in Seaborn. For Seaborn, you can get the relevant HEX color representation of color_palette as follows and was wondering how can I get similar color information in Altair.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.color_palette('Set2').as_hex()
    Out[131]: 
    ['#66c2a5',
     '#fc8d62',
     '#8da0cb',
     '#e78ac3',
     '#a6d854',
     '#ffd92f',
     '#e5c494',
     '#b3b3b3']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color palettes used by Altair are realized in the Vega-Lite renderer, as defined by the [vega-scale](https://github.com/vega/vega-scale) package.

A human-readable summary is in the [Color Schemes](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/) section of the Vega documentation. The color schemes are actually defined in [schemes.js](https://github.com/vega/vega-scale/blob/master/src/schemes.js) and [palettes.js](https://github.com/vega/vega-scale/blob/master/src/palettes.js).

Unfortunately, the color palette details are not available via Altair from the Python package itself.

Answer (score 9):

It seems like the default color palette of Altair (from the Vega-Lite renderer) is quite similar to Category 10:

```
#1f77b4, #ff7f0e, #2ca02c, #d62728, #9467bd,
#8c564b, #e377c2, #7f7f7f, #bcbd22, #17becf
```

The details of different palettes can be found here: https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/Ordinal-Scales/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like my charts in altair are actually using the [Tableau 10 color scheme](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/schemes/#tableau10). Hexes are:

```
#4c78a8
#f58518
#e45756
#72b7b2
#54a24b
#eeca3b
#b279a2
#ff9da6
#9d755d
#bab0ac
```