# For Altair (python) visualizations, is there a way to create color scheme that combines a manual range and an existing Vega-specified scheme?

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair, vega

For any given chart, I'd like to specify the first *n* colors for `alt.Scale(range=), and then if there are _n+1_ data values, for Altair to fallback on color scheme, e.g.` 'category10'`.

In the following example, if there are 6 `name` values, Altair will render them in `red` and `green` in a cyclical sequence:

```py
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(x='name', y='amount',
   fill=alt.Color('name', 
          scale=alt.Scale(range=['red', 'green'])))
```

However, what I would like to happen is for `name` values 3 through 6 to be, say, the first 4 colors of a scheme, like `category10`. Pretend the Altair API recognized this kind of call (it doesn't, obviously, just trying to explain in code):

```py
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(x='name', y='amount',
   fill=alt.Color('name', 
          scale=alt.Scale(range=['red', 'green'], scheme='category10'
    )))
```

I guess another way I could ask my question is, is there a way to access a colorscheme object, and then manually tweak its color sequence? Here's another pseudocode explanation of what I mean:

```py
mycolors = alt.Scale(range=['red', 'green']) + alt.Scale(scheme='category10')
chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(x='name', y='amount',
   fill=alt.Color('name', scale=mycolors))
```

According [to this answer from jakevdp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54030147/160863), "the color palette details are not available via Altair from the Python package itself", which makes sense. But is there a way to essentially to designate/customize a new scheme, using existing specified schemes?